# Google Map geocoding is not validating the correct address

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I have correct address 
700 Bay Rd
Redwood City
CA 94063
United States

But google map geocoding is not returning result for this address, I am using the url (removed the api key for here only):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94063|locality:Redwood%20City|administrative_area:CA

but when I removed the locality, it is working even though locality is same in response from below request
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94063|administrative_area:CA

Can anybody help on this??

Comment: Why are you using components and not the address? https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=700%20Bay%20Rd%20Redwood%20City%20CA%2094063%20United%20States

Comment: why there is issue in using components for this address only. It is working fine for all other addresses. Issues are for few addresses only.

Comment: What is your problem with it: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94063|locality:Redwood%20City|administrative_area:CA&address=700%20Bay%20Rd%20Redwood%20City%20CA%2094063%20United%20States

Comment: Why you are keep on running code your way, not the way  I am saying
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94063|locality:Redwood%20City|administrative_area:CA

is there any nothing wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, Google announced the new version of Geocoding API:

https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html

This version is now default. It looks like your query is broken in the new geocoder, but works correctly in the old version:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:94063|locality:Redwood%20City|administrative_area:CA&new_forward_geocoder=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I would suggest reporting the issue in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

Hope it helps!